# how to omit parenthesis in return from a python def

Tags: python, function, parentheses

Hello I am trying to build a function to count words, the return has to be "salad:0 hamburger:2 water:1" Notice that each item is formatted as name of the item,a colon symbol,count of the item and all item groups are separated by a space, what I am getting is the following ('salad:', 1, 'hamburger:', 2, 'water:', 2) how can I take all the () and '' off of the return

my code the following:

```
def item_order (order = ""):

    order = order

    s = order.count('salad')
    h = order.count('hamburger')
    w = order.count('water')

    return 'salad:',s, 'hamburger:',h, 'water:',w                       

print  item_order('water hamburger water hamburger salad')
```

Comment: You can't, the result is a tuple. If you need it formatted differently for display, do that *outside*, or return a string.

Comment: BTW, the line `order = order` is redundant...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in previous comments, you are returning a `tuple`, which, when printed, produces the output you are getting

```
('salad:', 1, 'hamburger:', 2, 'water:', 2)
```

In case you want to return a single string with the mentioned format you can do

```
return ' '.join(('salad:', str(s), 'hamburger:', str(h), 'water:', str(w)))
```

which, for example, produces

```
'salad: 1 hamburger: 2 water: 2'
```

Answer (score 1):

You are returning a **tuple**, therefore it is normal to have paranthesis if you print it.

The problem is, why do you need the result without paranthesis ? Given that there is no such data type in python. If you need that for displaying, you can print it like this

```
for elem in result:
    print elem,
# salad: 1 hamburger: 2 water: 2
```

If you need to make the whole result a string, that is a different issue, so you see, you need to decide what do you need in this case.

So if the issue is the second one, you can use this:

```
result = ('salad:', 1, 'hamburger:', 2, 'water:', 2)
print str(result)[1:-1]
# 'salad:', 1, 'hamburger:', 2, 'water:', 2
```

If you need a string and also need the quotes removed, you can return the function like this

```
return 'salad:' + str(s) + ' hamburger:' + str(h) + ' water:' + str(w)
```

Comment: Hi Rockybilly, what I am being asked is to create a string like this "salad:0 hamburger:2 water:1"  but that has to be the return; because when I try to display the result outside the function differently still grades me incorrect, can you you tell me how to get a string as return ?

Comment: **return 'salad:' + str(s) + ' hamburger:' + str(h) + ' water:'  + w** should do the trick. Let me add it to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your function is returning *a tuple*, so when passed to `print` that tuple gets printed. And tuples are printed within parentheses.

You could import the Python 3 print function and pass the tuple as arguments to the function. For that, you need to add the following import at the very top of your file:

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

And then you can do it like so:

```
print(*item_order('water hamburger water hamburger salad'))
```

Note that importing the print function will require you to always use `print(something)` instead of `print something`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you have only these words you're counting, probably the easiest way to output them with the counts would be, to return a string concatenated from the words you're counting and their counts like so:

```
def item_order (order=""):

    order = order

    s = order.count('salad')
    h = order.count('hamburger')
    w = order.count('water')

    return 'salad: ' + str(s) + ' hamburger: ' + str(h) + ' water: ' + str(w)                       

print item_order('water hamburger water hamburger salad')
```

Comment: Concatenating multiple strings using `+` is inefficent in Python, it's better to do it with `str.join`, `str.format` or `%`-style string formatting.

Answer (score 0):

You are producing a tuple of the form `('salad:', 1, 'hamburger:', 2, 'water:', 2)`.

You can use [.format](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) to easily turn that into a string:

```
>>> t=('salad:', 1, 'hamburger:', 2, 'water:', 2)
>>> "{} {}, {} {}, {} {}".format(*t) 
'salad: 1, hamburger: 2, water: 2'
```